# Sensor VL53L0X in Labview with MyRio

Tags: sensors, labview

Good day everyone,

I am trying to receive distance data from VL53L0X sensor, but I can't do it with this simple code. I am trying to translate the [API language in Arduino](https://github.com/pololu/vl53l0x-arduino) to the Labview language, but I am struggling with it. Can anybody help me?

This simple code doesn't work:
[image]

Thanks in advance
S.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by addressing the i2c device.

In your code you are inexplicably calling a myrio subvi, write down what you want to do and try and implement, if you need help then post here.

Comment: I tried to use the I2C bus equal to what this person did in this [link] (https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/i2c-on-myRIO-1900/td-p/3681513). The only change that I made in my code (different from the image I posted) was change the 'open I2C' to a 'smart open I2C', but It continue to not return the distance. I'm trying to make a simple measurement using sensor VL53L0X with MyRio.